Why doesn't autocompletion for Avalonia work in VS Code on Linux
I have downloaded extensions for c# and avalonia ui, but auto completion does not work.
While in .axaml.cs code everything works fine
I rebooted vs code and reinstalled but it doesn't help

Hi,
have you found a solution?

Unfortunately no. It worked for me before, but after reinstalling vs code, autocompletion stopped working for me.
